# Android how to add text form a JSON Feed into a Lazy adapter

Tags: android, text, lazy-loading

Hi i currently have a lazy adapter loading in images now i want to add the text to go along side the images. it currently says item 0 item 1 etc. i have  a Json Feed that i want to replace it with. so my question really is how do i change the text in a lazy adapter and replace it with an arrayList?

heres what i have so far.

```
try {
        post.setEntity (new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        String json = reader.readLine();
        fulldata = String.valueOf(json);
        Log.v("myApp","newsdata" + fulldata);

        newsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        newsList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        newsList3 = new ArrayList<String>();
        imageList = new ArrayList<String>();


        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);    
        JSONObject objData = obj.getJSONObject("data");
        JSONArray jArray = objData.getJSONArray("news");


           for(int t = 0; t < newsAmount; t++){
               JSONObject newsTitleDict = jArray.getJSONObject(t);
               imageList.add(newsTitleDict.getString("image_small"));
             newsList3.add(newsTitleDict.getString("title"));

           }

           for(int t = 0; t < 1; t++){
               JSONObject newsTitleDict = jArray.getJSONObject(t);

             newsList.add(newsTitleDict.getString("title"));
             newsList2.add(newsTitleDict.getString("title"));

           }



    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }




    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.single_item, newsList);
    arrayAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.single_item, newsList2);
    //arrayAdapter3 = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.complex_item, newsList3);



     String[] mStrings = (String[]) imageList.toArray(new String[imageList.size()]);



     arrayAdapter3 = new LazyAdapter(this, mStrings);


        ListView list = getListView();
           list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

           LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
            View header = inflater.inflate( R.layout.homeheader, list, false);
            View header2 = inflater.inflate( R.layout.homeheader2, list, false);
            View header3 = inflater.inflate( R.layout.homeheader3, list, false);


    //setListAdapter (arrayAdapter);






        adapter = new MergeAdapter();
        adapter.addView(header);
        adapter.addAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        adapter.addView(header2);
        adapter.addAdapter(arrayAdapter2);
        adapter.addView(header3);
        adapter.addAdapter(arrayAdapter3);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

Lazy Adapter

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private String[] data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, String[] d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

        TextView text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text);;
        ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
        text.setText("item "+position);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], image);
        return vi;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's in the answer I posted on one of your earlier questions. The example has a picture (as per your requirement in that question) and Text implemented in a similar way. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10616817/450534